# Qual país teve a maior população total em cada ano

Tags: mysql, sql, query, select

Eu criei esta tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE `Populacao` (
  `ano` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pais` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `popM` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `popF` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
);
```

Onde popM é a população masculina e popF é a população feminina.

Estou a tentar descobrir (query) que país teve a maior população total em cada ano.

```
Nota 1: População total = popF + popM
Nota 2: popM e popF são campos 'varchar'
```

Comment: Qual versão do MySQL você está utilizando? Existe a possibilidade de alterar as colunas popM e popF para integer ou algum tipo numérico?

Comment: Quais valores o seu sistema está enviando para as colunas popM e popF ?

Comment: MySQL 5. Não, quero manter popM e popF varchar.

Comment: Envia "83456765", por exemplo. Valores numéricos, mas em varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça uma subquery que gere a relação das maiores populações para cada ano:

```
SELECT ano, max(cast(coalesce(popM, '0') AS unsigned)+cast(coalesce(popF, '0') AS unsigned)) AS maxpop
FROM Populacao
GROUP BY ano;
```

De posse desta relação determine qual(is) pais(es) tem aquela população naquele ano:

```
SELECT Populacao.ano, Populacao.pais, x.maxpop FROM Populacao
INNER JOIN (SELECT ano, max(cast(coalesce(popM, '0') AS unsigned)+cast(coalesce(popF, '0') AS unsigned)) AS maxpop
            FROM Populacao
            GROUP BY ano) x
ON (Populacao.ano =x.ano AND (cast(coalesce(Populacao.popM, '0') AS unsigned)+cast(coalesce(Populacao.popF, '0') AS unsigned)) = x.maxpop);
```

Corrigido.